# Convert string to generic type c# (Convert string to T)

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion

I have a method that needs to convert a string to the generic type:

```
T GetValue<T>(string name)
{
   string item = getstuff(name);
   return item converted to T   // ????????
}
```

T could be int or date.

Comment: If `T` can be *only* `int` or `DateTime`, don't use generics. If `T` could be other types as well, see [Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: `return (T)Convert.ChangeType(item, typeof(T));`

Comment: See if the [Convert.ChangeType(obj, type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method suits your needs.

Comment: I have to agree that that that is a bad use of a generic method.  You should simply write a separate method for int and DateTime.  You can make it work but that certainly doesn't mean that you should.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can use [Convert.ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
T GetValue<T>(string name)
{
   string item = getstuff(name);
   return (T)Convert.ChangeType(item, typeof(T));
}
```

if you need to limit input types only for int and DateTime, add condition like below

```
if (typeof(T) != typeof(int) && typeof(T) != typeof(DateTime))
{
     // do something with other types 
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly converting a string to a date or int depending on what T was. Thanks

Comment: Bad idea.  What's to stop T being some other type?  There is far too much that can go wrong with that code.