# How to convert string to T in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift4

I need a method that converts string to the generic type:

i tried this so far but it doesn't work on Int objects. When i pass object as Int to this method, it won't return Int result. Can you please help me.
An example;

```
let k : Int
gg(k,"testUrl") // Problem: this method call can't return int value.

func gg<T:Decodable>(_ nesne: T, _ URL: String) -> (T) {
   var returnValue : T?
   let data = "123" // <-- from web service
   returnValue = data as! T
   return returnValue
}
```

Comment: what is data in (String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8))?

Comment: Question is clear. He created a generic function but it is not working with int objects... That means it can't convert string to int on return with generic function. If there is any solution or explanation about this problem, simply you can answer the question. being that much rude is not neccecary.

Comment: Question is clear and a similar question exists in c #: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21807729/convert-string-to-t

Comment: @ReadyFreddy, instruction highly unclear and everything is a gibberish here: e.g. if that is an _asynchronous_ method, why there is no completion handler? if that is a _synchronous_ method what is deal with networking? etc... mess, mess, and mess... on so many levels (while the linked post is clear and understandable).

Comment: @holex question is not about your criticsms. Not about networking, not about handling completions. Question is clearly "why this method not returning int value". You can say " method won't convert string value to int value automaticaly" or something like that. You are not recruiting workers here or not making an exam for your students. you are trying to help people.

Comment: and even if you want to criticise people about coding, you will make it "friendly". not orcish style...

Comment: @ReadyFreddy, since there is no way to figure out what OP wants (based on the messy and gibberish code snippet what does not even compile!) this question either could be marked as _unclear_ or _too board_ or _opinion-based_ – pick one what fits better until the question is cleaned up; in its current state that is not helpful for anyone in the community – or please, please feel free to provide answer if you _think_ this question is clearly stated and obvious, I'm looking forward to see you trying; until that, let's try to figure out what is this question about, shall we?

Comment: Is this about creating a generic JSON retrieval and decoding function?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how you can decode a string to a generic type without defining a decoder so either you need a new class that implements `Decoder` or you create a new protocol to be implemented for types that you want to use with this function. Here is my implementation where I use a protocol.

```
protocol EncodeFromString {
    associatedtype T
    func encodeFrom(_ str: String) -> T?
}

extension Int: EncodeFromString {
    typealias T = Int
    func encodeFrom(_ str: String) -> Int? {
        return Int(str)
    }
}

func gg<T: EncodeFromString>(_ nesne: T, _ URL: String) -> (T?) {
    let data = "123"
    return nesne.encodeFrom(data) as? T
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> In general, `String` type can not be always successfully converted to other types, however, you can implement it by your self.

## Example

```
class Functional<T> {
    var t: String
    var need: T {
        get {
            // you can support other types here
            if T.self == Int.self{
                let re = Int(self.t)
                return re as! T
            }
            fatalError()
        }
    }
    init(t_: String)  {
        t = t_
    }
}
let k : Int = 5
func gg<T>(_ nesne: T, _ URL: String) -> (T) {
    let data = "123"
    let a = Functional<T>(t_: data)
    return a.need
}
print(gg(k, "hello"))
```